# Display list that is filtered after "keydown" with textbox using knockoutjs

Tags: google-maps, knockout.js

I have been learning knockout for about 2 months so maybe this a dumb question. I've been trying to create a list that will be filtered by a text input. This filter will also hide/show markers on the map at the same time. I dont really know if me issue is on the knockout side or the html binding side. Could you please address me to the right direction? This is the sample code of the code with the issue:

```
self.filteredPlaces = ko.computed(function() {
      var filter = self.query().toLowerCase();
      if (!filter) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.markers(), function (item) {
          item.setVisible(true);
          //I used the console.log to verify that the info was being fetch
          console.log(item.city);
        });
        return self.markers();
      } else {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.markers(), function(item) {
          // set all markers visible (false)
          var result = (item.city().toLowerCase().search(filter) >= 0);
          item.setVisible(result);
          return result;
        });
      }
    });
```

Also I have a link to a Fiddle setup [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4l63rt0/tugzy9r3/1/)

Comment: You're not binding knockout objects to your view. In order to do this you need to use "ko.applybindings(viewmodel)" in your initMap function, which will get the text:city bindings to appear. Next, you need to call subscribe on your query() observable.

Comment: Could you please help me how to do it

Comment: Ok, no problem. Start by doing what I suggested regarding initMap and ko.applyBindings that will get your list to show up. Do you see the list now?

Comment: It may be easier to show you. let me know if you want to use a chat room.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I'm going to work on it tonight, It was really busy this last days. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi again Jonathan, Finally I was able to make it work with your help. Here is the link of the changes I made: https://jsfiddle.net/4l63rt0/tugzy9r3/3/

Comment: Happy to help. Would you mind accepting the answer I've posted below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `ko.applyBindings(viewModel)` in `initMap` to bind the knockout objects to your view. From [the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) :

> To activate Knockout, add the following line to a `<script>` block:
>   `ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);`

Additionally, you need to `subscribe` to your query observable so that you can take action when the query changes.

> For advanced users, if you want to register your own subscriptions to
>   be notified of changes to observables, you can call their subscribe
>   function. For example:

```
myViewModel.personName.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    alert("The person's new name is " + newValue);
});
```

Comment: I don't know why, but there was no need to subscribe